# How to update the anchorPane in JavaFX having custom components in each node?

Tags: javafx-2

I have an AnchorPane. It will hold the objects of the custom class summaryData.

The summaryData class is as follows

```
public summaryData (double rectX, double rectY, double width, double height) {
    rect = new Rectangle(rectX,rectY,width,height);
    rect.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.GRAY);
    rect.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);

    text  = new Text();

    text.setFont(Font.font(ChartFontUtil.getAverageFont().getFamily(),FontWeight.NORMAL,11));       

    text.setY(rectY+((rect.getHeight() + text.getFont().getSize())/2)-1);       
    text.setSmooth(true);
    getChildren().add(rect);
    getChildren().add(text);
}
```

Now the objects of this class are added into the AnchorPane by the below statement

```
anchorPANE.getChildren().add(rectGroup);
```

where rectGroup is an object of the class summaryData.

Now I wanted to change the text set on this rectangles. So I have to perform setText().
But in case of update how do I reach to this component?
I mean I am having all nodes of the anchor pane like below

```
javafx.collections.ObservableList<Node> allRectGroups = anchorPANE.getChildren();
```

Now, is there any method that will refer the children of this rectGroup object through NODE

```
for(Node node : allRectGroups)
{
    // can this node will have any access to the object of class summaryData ?
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking to downcast? I.e. `summaryData data = (summaryData) node ;`?

Comment: Yes ... I tried it... but at that point of time it didn't work.... But it seems now it is working without any compile time error...

Comment: Actually I was trying to downcast Rectangles directly from it rather than the summaryData object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to downcast node to SummaryCountRect try this :

```
for(Node node : allRectGroups)
   {
     SummaryCountRect data = (SummaryCountRect) node ;
   }
```